# how can i upload audio file to server in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
NSString *urlString1 = @"http://www.php.eminosoft.com/123singles/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString1]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; 

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"song.mp3\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[NSString stringWithString:secondString]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"demo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"5"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I am getting response like:

> "file uploaded successfully"

but the problem is the file content size is in bytes, the audio file is not support to play.

Please help to me, How to upload a audio file to server?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  You say the problem is the "file content size is in bytes".  Can you explain your problem more?

Comment: dont make a "sendSynchronousRequest". go for async request with NSURLConnection. it should resolve the issue.

Comment: where is the mp3 NSData content? It is written '[body appendData:[NSString stringWithString:secondString]];' where it should be

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the audio file using FTP as the audio file is big in size and hence will take long time to get uploaded on server. FTP reduces that time period. Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please post code for uploading audio file with FTP ar any other helpful tutorial etc..

Answer (score 0):

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to upload an audio file like below,

```
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:SoundPath];
//SoundPath is your audio url path of NSDocumentDirectory.
[request addData:postData withFileName:@"myAudio.caf" andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"company_audio"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

This way you can easily upload audio file on server.

Comment: hardik can you give me your  sample code for the uploading i have trouble in my code and i cant get any solution my application hang while uploading .

Comment: @Hardik Shah: Is Only these lines of code  sufficient to send audio file to server. because I have tried this code but it didn't work. should I add anything else in above code?